# Identification of incoming http requests in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, client-server

Have a little problem.
I have some task, where must process some data in client server system.
On client side i can create diferent http request on JS.
For example:

```
$http.post(url, DataObj);
$http.get(url, DataObj);
$http.insert(url, DataObj);
$http.deletet(url, DataObj);
$http.update(url, DataObj);
```

On the server side on NodeJS I can identify type of request, get request data and do some server logic, after that i can send back some ansver or data object.
Node JS example:

```
var apiRoutes = express.Router();
apiRoutes.post('route', function(req, res) {
someFunction(req.params.data);
res.send(ResponseDataObj);  }
or
apiRoutes.delete('route', function(req, res) { .... }
```

The problem is that I can not understand how client-side PHP must identify the type of request (post, update, actually), get request data to process it and send the result result data.
Can I do all these manipulations in a single script, or must to make a few
scripts for each operation with data like a :

```
getData.php
insertData.php
updateData.php
deleteData.php
```

If anyone have a similar task please share code examples that I could understand, or reference to examples. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the request method in PHP using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`. However for a more structured approach (as you're doing with `Express`) I would advice using a lightweight framework to do the heavy lifting for you. These come to mind:

[Slim Framework](http://www.slimframework.com)

[Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com/)

[Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/)